# C# loops: iterating through an array

Tags: c#, loops

If I have a loop such as below:

```
foreach (string pass in new string[] { "pass1", "pass2", "pass3" })
{
 x = pass; //etc
}
```

does the anonymous string array get created once initially, or recreated once for each pass?

I believe the former, but collegues are convinced this is a bug waiting to happen because they say every iteration of the foreach loop results in a new string array being created.

The VS Disassembly code suggests I am right, but I want to be sure.

The reason we are looking at this is to try to understand a mysterious bug that reports that a collection has been changed whilst iterating over it.

Comment: You can easily test it, put a `DateTime` value for example instead of strings and inspect the members in each iteration.

Comment: Another way to show them it's only evaluated once is to step through the code in debug mode. The code that creates the string array will only be highlighted once.

Comment: or `new string[] { "pass1", "pass" + i++, "pass3" }`

Comment: "a mysterious bug that reports that a collection has been changed whilst iterating over it" - why not post THAT as the question?

Comment: "a mysterious bug that reports that a collection has been changed whilst iterating over it." - this suggests you have code that is removing items from a collection inside of a loop. that's what you should be hunting for

Comment: why not post THAT as the question? – D Stanley 37 mins ago : that would require a shed load of code, because it's not clear where the problem is being caused (only where it is manifesting itself).

Comment: "this suggests you have code that is removing items from a collection inside of a loop": would this not also occur if an element is being changed in value (perhaps a property of the element pointing to a different object on the heap?

Comment: @haughtonomous: Is the problem you're talking about the same exception that you get if you run `var list = new List<int>() { 0 }; foreach (int x in list) { list.Add(0); }`? If so then modifying an element won't be the problem, only modifying the collection itself is relevant.

Comment: I presume this would be the same as

foreach (var rec in Database.ListMillionsOfRecords()) 

Database gets hit once.

Comment: "only modifying the collection itself is relevant." I think so, but I can't for the life of me find where the collection is being modified. I suspect some Linq deferred execution is tripping me up, so that's my next line of enquiry. But the internal 'debate' has been firmly settled by independant voices, so thanks to all for that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to [Eric Lippert blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) and [specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), foreach loop is a syntactic sugar for:

```
{
  IEnumerator<string> e = ((IEnumerable<string>)new string[] { "pass1", "pass2", "pass3" }).GetEnumerator();
   try
   { 
     string pass; // OUTSIDE THE ACTUAL LOOP
      while(e.MoveNext())
      {
        pass = (string)e.Current;
        x = pass;
      }
   }
   finally
   { 
      if (e != null) ((IDisposable)e).Dispose();
   }
}
```

As you can see, enumerator is created before loop.

@Rawling correctly pointed, that array treated a little different by compiler. *Foreach* loop is optimized into *for* loop with arrays. According to [The Internals of C# foreach](http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/09/the-internals-of-c-foreach/) your code for C# 5 will look like:

```
string[] tempArray;
string[] array = new string[] { "pass1", "pass2", "pass3" };
tempArray = array;

for (string counter = 0; counter < tempArray.Length; counter++)
{
    string pass = tempArray[counter];
    x = pass;
}
```

Initialization also happens only once.

Comment: +1 Starting from C# 5.0, the variable `pass` would be inside the loop.

Comment: @DominicKexel good notice, in c# 5 pass  variable will be declared inside loop, but enumerator still will be created before loop :)

Comment: I think this is subtly different for an array... doesn't it turn a `foreach` loop into a `for` loop?

Comment: @OferZelig The loop variable (`pass` in this case) is no longer outside the actual loop.

Comment: Argh, seems I accidently deleted my previous comment, but Botz3000 says the same in his comment :-)

Comment: The IL generated under linqpad 4.43 is very different from OP and this answer. I don't think the syntactic sugar applies in this case.

Comment: @lazy To be honest, your first code block is the best answer because it's what the spec says (8.8.4) - the `for` loop for arrays is just a bit of optimisation.

Comment: I try my best :) (Don't always succeed...)

Comment: @Rawling thanks a lot! Btw its strange that specification directly not says that foreach-loop for arrays is optimized into for-loop. There is only remark `An implementation is permitted to implement a given foreach-statement differently, e.g. for performance reasons, as long as the behavior is consistent with the above expansion`

Comment: Does moving the pass declaration inside the loop have any non-cosmetic effects?

Comment: @DanNeely yes, for closures. If variable declared outside loop, then only last variable value will be caputred by all delegates

Comment: Thanks - question answered.

Answer (score 5):

If you look in ILSpy, this code is translated into something like

```
string[] array = new string[]
{
    "pass1",
    "pass2",
    "pass3"
};
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    string pass = array[i];
}
```

so yes, the array is only created once.

However, the best reference to convince your colleagues is probably section 8.8.4 of the C# specification, which will tell you essentially what LazyBerezovsky's answer does.

Comment: +1 and thanks for pointing on different foreach compiling for arrays!

Answer (score 2):

It is created only once initially.

I tried the suggestion by Ofer Zelig (from the comments)

```
foreach (DateTime pass in new DateTime[] { DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now })
{
    int x = pass.Second; //etc
}
```

And placed a breakpoint. It will give the same seconds for all 3 iterations even if you wait between iterations.

Comment: Nice way to ensure :) I recommend using `new[] { DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now }` to make code look shorter :)

Answer (score 1):

You could test it (plenty of ways to do so, but this is one option):

```
string pass4 = "pass4";
foreach (string pass in new string[] { "pass1", "pass2", "pass3", pass4 })
{
    pass4="pass5 - oops";
    x = pass; //etc
}
```

Then see what comes out.

You'll find you're right - its only executed the one time.

Comment: Thanks - question answered.

Answer (score 1):

The example below should answer the question if the array is recreated or not.

```
        int i = 0;
        int last = 0;

        foreach (int pass in new int[] { i++, i++, i++, i++, i++, i++, i++ })
        {
            if (pass != last)
            {
                throw new Exception("Array is reintialized!");
            }
            last++;
        }

        if (i > 7)
        {
            throw new Exception("Array is reintialized!");
        }
```